# Игнорируется условие в тернарном операторе

Tags: php, тернарный-оператор

Добавив условие в тернарный оператор, начало игнорироваться первое условие 
- empty($_POST['email'] - и вместо сообщения 'Укажите почтовый адрес' выводится 'Такая почта уже зарегистрирована'.

Почему так происходит?

```php
$_SESSION['email_empty'] =  empty($_POST['email']) ? 'Укажите почтовый адрес': '';


$_SESSION['email_empty'] =  empty($_POST['email']) ? 'Укажите почтовый адрес' : 
$email_exists[0] == $_SESSION['email'] ? 'Такая почта уже зарегистрирована' : 'valid';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы забыли про скобки.

Строка 'Укажите почтовый адрес' идёт и обрабатывается как следующее выражение для второго вопроса. А второй вопрос выдаёт этот результат.

```
$_SESSION['email_empty'] =  empty($_POST['email']) ? 'Укажите почтовый адрес' : (
$email_exists[0] == $_SESSION['email'] ? 'Такая почта уже зарегистрирована' : 'valid' ) ;
```

https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary